# Schema Best Practice: Is it ever OK to store duplicates of a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, schema

This is a general question about good schema design. In my case I'm using Rails 4 and PostgreSQL.

Let's say I have a `storefront`, with many `product`s. The store also has many `order`s, each with many `product`s.

On Monday, a customer pays for an `order`. So now, we have a `product` that belongs to both a `storefront` and an `order`.

On Tuesday, the store decides to change the price of one of the `products`.

Clearly, I don't want to change the record of what the customer purchased on Monday, so this leads me to believe I should store **two copies** of the `product` - one copy of what the store is selling *now* (ie Tuesday), another copy for what the *customer bought* on Monday.

However, I know that duplicating data like this something generally to be avoided.

Is there a best-practice for handling a situation like this?

Comment: one way or another, you'll probably have to dupe records. you have to maintain a historical record of "old" products, e.g. older prices, older versions, so your sales records can be viewed properly. either maintain a historical record in the storefront table, or copy EVERYTHING to the sales table. otherwise you'll go look up customer X's purchase of product Y on date Z, and get whatever Y's specs are "right now", instead of "back then".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only sounds like duplication because you're using the same name for them. One price is the price the customer *paid*. The other is the price a product is currently sold at. They're separate pieces of data, even though in a lot of the cases they have the same value. I'd just give them separate names (e.g. `Order#paid` v. `Product#price`), and store the `Product#price` in `Order#paid` at the time of the sale. That way the product price can be change however needed without affecting the order.

Comment: Yep. Duplicate = same value with the same meaning.